# Как я могу отправить qr код в виде фото пользователю в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, qrcode

У меня есть такой qr код в base64:

```
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
```

Что необходимо использовать или написать, чтобы его отправить через телеграм бота на aiogram человеку в виде фото?

Comment: Сохраняйте изображение QR-кода и отправляйте как фотографию

Comment: Я не знаю о каком изображении вы имели ввиду, у меня есть только этот непонятный текст...

Comment: QR-код - это обычная картинка, верно? Если Вы генерируете его сами, то значит и сохраняете сами. Откуда этот base64 у Вас?

Comment: Его сгенерировал сайт при сокращении ссылки, я получил саму ссылку сокращенную и этот qr код в base64 ( прошу заметить всё в формате json ), поэтому не думайте, что сайт мне отправил ссылку на картинку или саму картинку или ещё что-либо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного прогулявшись по просторам интернета, нашёл ответ на Англоязычном стеке, ссылка - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/how-do-you-decode-base64-data-in-python

Сперва я импортировал модуль `base64 ( import base64 )`, затем присвоил переменной текст в виде base64:

```
coded_string = '''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'''
```

После попытался отправить таким вот образом:

```
await bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        photo=base64.b64decode(coded_string)
        )
```

И всё успешно получилось, qr код быстро был отправлен мне в чат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]